# Use links to change ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

How would I use links to trigger an ng-switch?

My current html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix sidenav">
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="page='resources'">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="page='users'">Users</a></li>

</ul>

<div ng-switch on="page">
    <div ng-switch-when="resources">
        <h1>resources Div</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="users">
        <h1>Users</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
        <h1>Default</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'users';
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: And what happens when you run this code?

Comment: nothing. If I change the expressions that change `page` to a function that changes page and then `console.log($scope.page)` I can see that `page` is getting changed, but the switch doesn't occur.

Comment: Works here - http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/uYMSN/

Comment: I wonder why this is not working for me.

Comment: @Dogbert snippet is working correctly. Can we select an answer for this question?

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled on a similar problem and solved it by using an object rather then a property on the scope so that the values are not overridden by the ng-switch directive.

The difference between the question asked and this solution is that I change the page value from withing the ng-switch scope.

Declare nav object in the controller

```
$scope.nav = {
                 page : 1
             }
```

HTML

```
<div ng-switch="nav.page">
<div ng-switch-when="1">
    First page
    <a href="#" ng-click="nav.page=2">Resources</a>
</div>
<div ng-switch-when="2">
    Second page
    <a href="#" ng-click="nav.page=3">Resources</a>
</div>
<div ng-switch-when="2">
    Third page
</div>
```

Comment: Would love to know why this is the case for this setup. Thanks for the answer though, really helped me out!

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind your controller to the top level element. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hU2rG/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
     <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix sidenav">
         <li><a href="#" ng-click="page='resources'">Resources</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" ng-click="page='users'">Users</a></li>

     </ul>
     <div ng-switch on="page">
        <div ng-switch-when="resources">
           <h1>resources Div</h1>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="users">
           <h1>Users</h1>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default>
           <h1>Default</h1>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My controller is bound in the routeProvider in app.js, so that does not help my problem.